# Difference between @Bean and @Component when registering a filter?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using a custom filter in my Spring Boot application and it seems there are 2 ways of getting the filter registered.

> --> Register the filter using the @Bean

```
   @Bean
    public Filter AuthenticationFilter() {
        return new AuthenticationFilter();
    }
```

> --> Anotate the Filter using @Component

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {}
```

I am puzzled on what the difference is and why i should use one over the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's largely down to personal preference.

Using `@Component` requires component scanning to be enabled. Some people prefer not to use component scanning as they find that it makes it hard to determine where your beans are coming from. Declaring everything using `@Bean` methods avoids this but at the cost of writing (slightly) more Java configuration.

Another reason to use `@Bean` is that you may not have any control over the Filter's source, i.e. you can't annotate it with `@Component` so declaring it using an `@Bean` method is your only option.

Comment: But that is not 100 valid for springboot if I am correct. (I dont really understand what you means with "are coming from"
For spring boot the way to go is to just use Component and acquire you dependencies with Autowired. But maybe your point is another one and I didnt get it :)